# Is it possible to receive tags of a stopped Task in AWS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using AWS SDK to start and control certain ECS Tasks on AWS Fargate. `ECS.describeTasks()` can be called to receive details of tasks and the returned data includes `.tags` array.

As soon as the task is in `STOPPED` status, it seems that the tags are removed from the task.

[The AWS SDK documentation does not mention](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ECS.html#describeTasks-property) that `.tags` would be empty for stopped tasks. While the task is in any other status (also `DEPROVISIONING`), tags are available.

[The AWS ECS documentation "Tagging your resources
"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-using-tags.html) does not either discuss about lifecycle of tags. There is a sentence that "Tags are removed when a resource is removed", but I would not consider stopped tasks removed as they are still returned via API & Console.

**Is there any way to (programmatically) receive tags of a stopped tasks?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I was trying to use `ecs.listTagsForResource` method, but it gave me an error that task is stopped and it cannot retrieve tags. So the trick is to use `ecs.describeTasks` together with `include` param, which should be equal to `["TAGS"]` .